# Is there a way in the STUFF(... FOR XML) function in SQL to prevent duplicate values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path, stuff

To keep this short, here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    EmailAddress, 
    FormsSubmitted = STUFF(
      (
        SELECT ',' + SourceSubType
        FROM UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE a 
        WHERE a.EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, ''),
    DEDate
FROM UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE b
GROUP BY b.EmailAddress, b.DEDate
```

And, here's the result set it produces:
[image]

Is there a way to prevent duplicate values from showing up in the `FormsSubmitted` column from within the query above?  Or do I need to do some "post processing" to remove the duplicates?

Comment: Add a `DISTINCT` to the inner SELECT query?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thank you!!  That worked.  I thought about it but it wasn't very intuitive to me that it would work so I was exploring other options first.  Thanks again!  Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: All `STUFF` is doing here is removing the first character of a string; it has no control over the results returned from `FROM`. If you don't want multiple rows of the same value from the dataset, it's the dataset you need to define that in.

Comment: You should use this syntax `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)', 1, 1, '')` to avoid issues with XML escaping. And if you have SQL Server 2017+ you should use `STRING_AGG` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `DISTINCT` to the inner SELECT query.